# How can the SVN URL in Redmine be changed?

Tags: linux, svn, upgrade, redmine, svn-repository

I've installed Bitnami Redmine 2.5.0 stack onto a fresh new Ubuntu 12.0.4 VM. I've imported the old Redmine 1.2.1 db into a new db and finished the job with `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`.

Now I can login into the upgraded Redmine with my old user account.

After copying the old svn repo into the new VM I couldn't see the repos. I've checked the project repo settings and found out that the old repo URL `file:///home/svn` was not the same on the new VM. The new VM's home path is `home/user/` which changes the svn path into `file:///home/user/svn`. The URL box is grayed out when I try to edit the repo settings on the projects. My user on Redmine is an administrator.

Is there a practical way to globally change this path on Redmine (or SVN or Apache ???) or should I change the path settings on Linux? I want to change it globally because we have nearly 130 projects, so it isn't practical to edit the URLs one by one. I'm very inexperienced in Linux and mostly google my problems or ask my coworkers. So please guide me accordingly in simple terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest moving your repositories to the same path as on the old machine, this will save you a lot of time and headache.

Redmine is configured to access the repository locally on filesystem (i.e. it does not access Apache HTTP Server); it's not clear how your Apache HTTP Server is configured in regards of the repository located in `/home/user/svn`. You may need to adjust Apache's configuration (`httpd.conf`) file to point to the changed repository path.

Comment: Ok, I've moved my repo to the same path and it worked. Yesterday I forgot to mention that I wasn't able to write to the home root directory but today one of my coworkers solved this problem for me by moving the svn directory with sudo to the home root.

Now I have another problem but the subject has changed. Should I ask another question?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change 50+ repositories in one go by executing a simple SQL update query which replaced a part of the `url` field in the `repositories` table.

You may have to restart redmine for the changes to take effect (not sure about that).